# Present Simple for considerations

Tags: present-tense, present-simple

When we are considering something, in spoken English is it okay to use the Present Simple:

- So what's your plan?
- Well, I take the train to Boston. I go to his house. I sneak in and then I steal that piece you need while you stand outside waiting for me.

Is this grammatically okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. It is characteristic of informal speech, but in that context the present simple is often used for more-or-less immediate intentions.